# I want to wirte this $ cut -d. -f3 <<< "linuxbox.23566.MMDDYYYYHHMMSS.zip" | cut -c-8 in Korn Sheel script to get values

Tags: unix

Please provide korn script by using above cut command..

I am using above cut command in korn shell script like below. but I am getting error like `syntax error at line 1 : '<' unexpected`

```
filein=Testing.26966.03182014123041.zip
foldernm=`cut -d. -f3 <<< ${filein} | cut -c-8`
```

Please respond..

Thanks advance

Comment: filein=Testing.26966.03182014123041.zip

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an old version of `ksh` which does not support here-strings (`<<<`). Try using `echo` instead:

```
foldernm=`echo $filein | cut -d. -f3 | cut -c-8`
```

Comment: +1 Your answer was in delete mode when I posted. Deleting mine as you were first! `:)`